# c# doesn't work struct adding to list

Tags: c#, struct

I have

```
struct Park
{
...
}
```

and I need, to add 10 elements of this struct to List.

```
        public List<Park> Parks = new List<Park>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().CreatePark();
...
        }

        public void CreatePark()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Park temp = new Park();
                temp.ID = i;
                temp.Number = "abc";
                temp.Property = false;
                try
                {
                    Parks.Add(temp);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("oh no :(");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And this doesn't work. Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString()); - this shows struct element, but when I want to print all elements, from Parks it's not working.
Parks.Count shows 0.

Comment: Don't use `struct` unless you *really* understand the difference. You should be using `class` in almost every case.

Comment: `new Program().CreatePark();` <- when this is done, you don't have any reference to the `Program` object that has anything in `Parks`.

Comment: At which point is parks.count zero?

Comment: why are you creating a `new Program()` when you are (presumably) already in an instance of `Program`?

Comment: @Chris Because he's *not* in an instance of `Program`.

Comment: @Servy: D'oh! code blindness. I blame the fact that Visual studio always makes the main signature for me (on the rare occasions I'm not in web apps or linqpad) and that `public` and `static` are the same length string. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using the statement: `new Program().CreatePark();` the list of objects that you've created is not accessible after you create them.  You have already thrown away the instance of the object holding the `List`.  You have no way to access the list that you created to know what you had put in it.

The only thing the rest of your code could possibly do is create an entirely separate instance that has its own list, one that is entirely different from the one that you populated.

You'll need to hold onto the reference to the `Program` object if you want to inspect the list after you've populated it.

Comment: Is it worth adding that the user may have intended to just call `CreatePark()` without creating a new instance of `Program`? I can't see any reason to create a new instance of program like that...

Comment: @Chris It's absolutely fine to be creating an instance of an object in this context.  He wouldn't be able to access instance members any other way than with an instance.  It's not the only way the program could be structured, but it's certainly a valid approach to use if he resolves this minor issue.

Comment: Yeah, I'm misreading code. I'd personally feel more comfortable using a different object but you are right that it is valid, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Parks is an instance variable.

CreateParks is an instance method.

Main is a static method, so you can't access the instance method or variable from it.

new Program() creates a new instance of the Program class.

Since the newly created program is not stored in a variable, it is discarded, and you can't access its Parks list after that.

To access the Parks list, you need to keep a reference to the instance of the program class like this:

```
Program program = new Program();
program .CreateParks();
foreach(Park park in program .Parks)
{
  // Do something with the park
}
```

For anything more than a simple program, you will be better off having all the logic which isn't related to starting the program outside the Program class.

For example, you could create a new ParkManager class which is responsible for creating the parks and providing access to them.

Your program would look a bit like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        ParkManager parkManager = new ParkManager();
        parkManager.CreateParks();
        foreach (Park park in parkManager.Parks)
        {
            // do something with park

        } 
    }
}

public class ParkManager
{
    // Setter is private to prevent other classes from replacing the list
    // This doesn't prevent other classes from adding or removing,
    // replacing or editing items in the list
    public List<Park> Parks {get; private set;}

    // Constructor - you could populate the list from here if appropriate
    public void ParkManager()
    {
        Parks = new List<Park>();
    }

    public void CreateParks()
    {
      // Populate the list of parks here
    }
}
```